# Keytool complaining about X509 certificate even though it is valid

Tags: openssl, x509, keytool

**TL;DR:** Keytool refuses to import a certificate that has less than 1 day of validity

**LONG VERSION:** I am having an issue with keytool. I am creating a self-signed CA and SUBCA certfificate chain for testing purposes using openssl however I am having some issues importing it into keytool later.

I am creating CA the following way

> openssl rand -out ./private/.rand 1024
>
> openssl genrsa -out ./private/cakey.pem -aes256 -rand ./private/.rand 2048
>
> openssl req -days 365 -subj '/C=US/ST=SM/O=Company/OU=Org/CN=ROOT_CA/emailAddress=whatever@whatever.com' -x509 -new -key ./private/cakey.pem -out cacert.pem -config openssl.cnf

I will then create SUB_CA the exact same way as above (Different CN) and sign it with the root ca certfificate the following way

> openssl ca -startdate 120524100000Z -enddate 120524101500Z -in ../sub_ca/subcareq.pem -out ../sub_ca/cacert.pem -extensions v3_ca -config openssl.cnf

(Note the certificate above is valid for 15 minutes only)

Up until here everything is fine. The issue occurs when I try import both into a JKS. The Root certificate imports without an issue but the SUB_CA gives the follow problem

> keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias subca -file sub_ca/cacert.pem -keystore keystore.jks
>
> > Enter keystore password:
> >
> > Re-enter new password:
> >
> > keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Input not an X.509 certificate

I don't understand why it keeps saying that when it is a perfectly valid certificate. If I change the startdate and enddate of the certificate and instead give **1 day** (-days 1) as the validity when signing, it imports into the jks without an issue.

Does keytool have some sort of limitation where it can only import an X509 that is valid for more than 24 hours or something like that?

Comment: Your openssl statement uses different formats for start and end date. What happens if you use the same formats?

Comment: Sorry, that was a misspell. I have added the missing Z in the enddate.